# How to access fields from entry DE in Journey Builder via AMPscript?

Tags: ampscript, journeybuilder, automationstudio, mobilepush

I want to send a push message via MobilePush from inside a customer journey. The content of the push message should personalised with AMPscript, based on the entry audience of the journey, which is a data extension fired from an automation in Automation Studio.

My question now is: How can I access the fields from the entry DE (e.g. Firstname) inside the push message via AMPScript, for example to address the recipient with his first name?

Answer (score 0):

You must use lookup function and then find the First Name from the entry data extension.

Check below for lookup ampscript examples. https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples